# WPF MVVM : get a collection of cell-data corresponds to a column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Is there any way to get DataGridColumns cells-data as a collection of cell-data corresponds to this column?
Note that I'm using MVVM and my datagrid is being dynamically built by DataGridColumn collection!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are really using MVVM, then you will know that you *should* have all of the data that is displayed in the view in your related view model. If that is correct, then you will have a collection that is data bound to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property. As we work with *data* in WPF and *not UI elements*, then you can get a collection that contains all of the values from one column using `LinQ`.

Let's say that you have a column (and therefore a property of your data type) that you want to single out. Let's say that that property is a `string` and named `Name`. You can gather all of the values of that property from each item in the collection like this:

```
List<string> names = yourCollection.Select(i => i.Name).ToList();
```

If it were an `int` property named `Age`, you could do this... and so on:

```
List<int> ages = yourCollection.Select(i => i.Age).ToList();
```

Comment: I used cell style to get the cell data into a converter and continued from there.